# Users must have a secure screen-lock set Ionic 2 secure storage

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to replace ionic 2 Storage plugin with SecureStorage. But,in the documentation it is said that 'Users must have a secure screen-lock set'. So I am a bit confused. As it is also said that if the security setting is not sufficient then the app developer should inform the user about the security requirements of her app and initialize again after the user has changed the screen-lock settings. I think I don't need a security storage to that extant. So will it be a good idea to move 'Storage' to 'SecureStorage'. If not then what could be an alternative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So will it be a good idea to move 'Storage' to 'SecureStorage'

No, "Secure Storage" (provided by [cordova-plugin-secure-storage](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage)) is intended to store small amounts of sensitive data, such as user credentials or credit card details. It is not intended as a drop-in replacement for a general storage mechanism, such as a SQLite database (e.g [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)). It does not provided an unlimited amount of storage capacity, for example on Android, trying to storage more than around 1.5Mb will cause a memory exception. If you need to store larger amounts of sensitive data, you could encrypt the data stored in a larger SQLite database and use secure storage to safely store the decryption key, for example.

> in the documentation it is said that 'Users must have a secure screen-lock set'

This means that on Android, the device must have a secured lock screen - i.e. a pattern or pin code lock which must be entered to unlock the device (note: slide unlock is not considered secure). If this is not the case, then the secure storage plugin constructor function will invoke the error callback, and you won't be able to use secure storage to store data on that device.

> it is also said that if the security setting is not sufficient then the app developer should inform the user about the security requirements of her app and initialize again after the user has changed the screen-lock settings.

If the error callback is invoked when initialising the plugin, you have the opportunity to inform the user i.e. "Your device doesn't have a secure screen lock. Without one, you won't be able to {use this functionality}. Would you like to set one now?"

You can use whatever mechanism you like to present the message to the user, e.g. [the confirm() function from `cordova-plugin-dialogs`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs#navigatornotificationconfirm).

If the user agrees, you can call the `secureDevice()` function from the secure storage plugin, which invokes a native activity to walk the user through the process of setting up a screenlock. Your app will be put in the background during this, so when it resumes, you can use an `onResume()` handler to check if the secure storage plugin is already initialised and if not retry intialising it: if the user setup a screenlock, the plugin will successfully initialise. If not, the error callback will be invoked again (back to square one).

Also note that Android 4.4 or above is required by the secure storage plugin: on Android 4.3 or below, the plugin will always fail to intialise, regardless of the lock screen settings.